# How to count one column and adding up several columns at the same time using summarise in dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe (there are 20 more columns like `class` but just for the example I show a short version):

```
 niv  ID  class1 class2 class3
  A   x    10      5      7
  A   y    15      3      1
  A   z    11      2      4
  B   u    17      7      3
  B   w    18      7      9
```

So I wanted to `group_by(niv)` and to summarise the `ID` column just counting it and `class1`, `class2` and `class3` columns to add up in just one command. I tried `summarise_each` but I can't sort out how to use it. Also the objetive would be to learn how to mix different funs in the summarise function when you have a dataframe with a lot of columns.

The summarise dataframe I need is this one:

```
 niv  n_ID  sum_class1 sum_class2 sum_class3
  A    3        36         10         12
  B    2        35         14         12
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was mine, I sent it but it was incomplete so I erased it to post it with all the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `summarise` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(n_ID = 1) %>%
   group_by(niv) %>%
   summarise(across(starts_with('class'), sum))
```

---

With `across`, we can have multiple functions

```
iris %>%      
   summarise(across(where(is.factor), nlevels), 
            across(where(is.numeric), mean))
#  Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1       3     5.843333    3.057333        3.758    1.199333
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(niv = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), ID = c("x", 
"y", "z", "u", "w"), class1 = c(10L, 15L, 11L, 17L, 18L), class2 = c(5L, 
3L, 2L, 7L, 7L), class3 = c(7L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 9L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks. I ran the code an I got this: `Error across (starts_with ("class"), sum): function "across" could not be found`. Also what I want for future exercises is to learn how to combine count and sum in one summarise function.

Comment: @ErnestoRiverosBarrientos the function is in the new dplyr package version.  If you need the bleeding edge, install the devel version

Comment: I understand. Can you help me where to find the devel version?

Comment: @ErnestoRiverosBarrientos you can use `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")` (from [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `n_ID` column with all 1's and `sum` them with all `'class'` columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 mutate(n_ID = 1) %>%
 group_by(niv) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(n_ID, starts_with('class')), sum)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  niv    n_ID class1 class2 class3
#  <chr> <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 A         3     36     10     12
#2 B         2     35     14     12
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(niv = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), ID = c("x", 
"y", "z", "u", "w"), class1 = c(10L, 15L, 11L, 17L, 18L), class2 = c(5L, 
3L, 2L, 7L, 7L), class3 = c(7L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 9L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: That could solved it. But I also wanted to explore combining two funs in the summarise function.

Comment: @ErnestoRiverosBarrientos I don't get it which 2 functions do you want to combine? You are applying only `sum` function to columns `class1` ,`class2`etc.

Comment: There are two functions I want to use: count niv and sum the other numeric columns.

Comment: @ErnestoRiverosBarrientos Yes, so you are not actually combining two functions, right? Because you are counting only once. This gives you that I think. I am not exactly clear what you are looking for.

Comment: I think the `across` function suggested by @akrun can combine several functions in the summary function.